# Is this gif from a movie?

Tags: story-identification, horror, character-identification

I found this looking up creepy characters on Google.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you find this image?

Comment: Looks a bit like the boy from *Juon: the Grudge*.

Comment: Unclear how this is science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: They seem to me to be wearing a bridal headdress, swept back. Not sure this is on-topic either.

Comment: @JiminyCricket.: I do not have any software right now to do a frame by frame analysis, but I am quite sure that I see his / her hairs all around the had (at different moments in time) - which would exclude anything covering the head. I cannot be sure though. The white stuff around the head seems to be the halo created by some light source somewhere behind them - and the light source is not there permanently - it is like its purpose is just to create the halo temporarily.

Comment: @xXEdgy_OutsiderXx: this video clip might be as well from some (trailer of some) game. I judge this by the quality of the image. Also, considering that actually there are fragments of movement put together, without real continuity, might be further indication that it is taken from a trailer, not from the movie / game itself.

Comment: @Lexible - Brides typically have less makeup on

Comment: @virolino Oh, look. [It's a bride](http://thehorrorsyndicate.com/2016/07/review-the-innkeepers-2011/) :)

Comment: @JiminyCricket.: you are more right than I was. I saw the hairs, and I assumed it is only hairs. But I did not take into consideration that the headdress (veil) was _behind_ the head, instead of covering it - so actually they were both visible. I noticed this when I zoomed in into the video clip with the CTRL+scroll in the browser. The description of the movie supports this view too.

Comment: @Valorum Fair enough, but you hang around enough goth-inflected artists and this just seems like a Tuesday.

Answer (score 20):

[The Innkeepers (2011 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Innkeepers_(film))

> The Innkeepers is a 2011 American supernatural horror film written, directed and edited by Ti West. It stars Sara Paxton, Pat Healy, and Kelly McGillis. Its plot follows two employees at the Yankee Pedlar Inn who, during its last weekend of operations, attempt to document the alleged supernatural activity in the building.

[Here's a review of the film](https://whitecitycinema.com/2012/01/30/he-saidshe-said-review-the-innkeepers/), which contains the image below;

> [image]